# Custom class setup, methods and pragma marks layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I find my self rewriting the same Pragma marks, and basic code in over and over again.
For example, in every class i like to use Pragma marks as:

```
#Pragma mark - Setup

#Pragma mark - Buttons Actions
```

And so on...

Same at some methods like:

```
-(void)menuButtonPress;
```

So i'm wondering is there a way of making a default layout for classes, templates, of my own.

Any one knows how?

Thanks!

Comment: Well there are Xcode snippets, but every class is different, with different methods etc. so I think you would spend more time maintaining snippets than writing code.  I never use snippets as I cannot be bothered to even learn the keystrokes required.

Comment: Right snippets! i totally forgot about them, Thanks! (: